# Laravel - pass value to registration form

Tags: laravel, forms, registration

I couldn't find the route to the /register form in laravel. What I wanted to do is to add a variable that is passed..

mysite/register?referral=123456

when you load the page the referral textbox with id="referral" should be prefilled. How can this be done?

Comment: u cant try `request()->get('referral')` then return the value to view

Comment: @Aslam that worked! thank you! can you post it as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the request param

```
public function register()
{
  $referral = request()->get('referral');
  if (empty($referral)) {
    $referral = '';
  }
  return view('register', compact('referral'))
}
```